# how to UV unwrap a material

Tags: materials, uv

Is it possible to UV unwrap only a material? I have on object with multiple materials and I would like to apply a texture only to one of them.
Thanks for answers

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can unwrap only a mesh, because unwrapping is projecting 2D texture onto the 3D object. After unrwap is done you apply materials to a mesh to be able to aaply textures. Then to apply a texture to only one material you simply select adjacent material and add texture / texture node (depends on engine) only for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clarify, you don't unwrap a texture, you unwrap a mesh. UV unwrapping is a way of defining the translation between a spot on a 3D object to a spot on a 2D image.

You can create multiple UV maps for an object and choose a specific UV map to use for a texture image. When you want to use more than one image for an object you don't have to use the same UV map for each image.

When UV unwrapping, the UV layout shown in the UV/Image Editor is the data associated with the UV map highlighted in the UV Map list. The UV map with a little camera next to it is the default layout that will be used if no specific UV map is chosen.

[image]

When using Blender Internal you choose the UV map to use in the Mapping panel of the texture settings.

[image]

For cycles instead of using a Texture Coordinate node, you add a UV map node and choose the UV map.

[image]